# Insertion Resistance of Current Transformers

Tags: resistance, current-measurement, current-transformer, insertion, wire-loop

Given a current transformer like this:

[image: typical current transformer]

there is an insertion resistance that appears as a very small equivalent series resistance on the measured circuit.  Since it is usually small (say, 0.0001 \$\Omega\$), it can be neglected.

If you were to feed the current-carrying wire you are trying to monitor through the transformer multiple times to amplify your signal, does this also multiply the insertion resistance by the same amount?  If I loop the wire through 10 times, does this multiply the insertion resistance by a factor of 10?

To clarify what I am asking, [here is a link](http://%20pearsonelectronics.com/insertion-resistance) describing what insertion resistance means in the context of the type of transformer shown above.

Comment: Reflected impedance in a transformer goes as the square of the number of turns.

Answer (score 1):

As JohnD hinted, the impedance ratio of a transformer is equal to the square of the turns ratio.

So if you have a 1000:1 transformer with a burden resistance of 100 ohms, the "reflected" resistance on the primary will be

$$\frac{100 \Omega}{1000^2} = 0.1 m\Omega$$

If you change the turns ratio to 1000:10 (= 100:1), but keep the burden resistance the same, the reflected impedance becomes:

$$\frac{100 \Omega}{100^2} = 10 m\Omega$$

... which is 100× as large, not 10×.

Comment: Interesting, but for most current transformers, like the one above, the # of turns is not given.  At most, the output voltage for a given input current is.  Is that sufficient for calculating the effective insertion resistance?

Comment: I think you're confusing two current-measuring technologies. Current-sensing *resistors* are usually specified in terms of voltage drop for a given maximum current, which is really just another way of specifying their resistance. Current-sensing *transformers* are always specified in terms of their turns ratios, along with their maximum current rating.

Comment: ... but in any case, in terms of your specific question, the exact number of turns on the secondary doesn't matter -- regardless of what it is, if you have 10x the turns in the primary and keep everything else the same, the primary impedance will go up by 100x.

Comment: thanks, I'm just going off of the mfg's website.  They refer to insertion resistance when using their current transformer.  Here's the link:  http://www.pearsonelectronics.com/insertion-resistance

Comment: What about the DCR of the secondary and the burden resistance .this also gets reflected

Comment: @Autistic: I don't understand your question. Isn't that what I said in my answer? (Usually, the DCR of the secondary is insignificant with respect to the burden resistance.)

Comment: I was worried if there were lots of turns on the sec and if the CT was physicly small .you did the burdon but the total burdon is DCR + 100 ohm ? or is the total including DCR 100 ohm ? .others could get confused ,Dont worry about me getting confused because I find the world confusing .